# How to overwrite image if file type is different in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I used `$config['overwrite']=TRUE;` to update user profile picture, It overwrites only if both file name and file type is same else copies to new file, example(101.png, 101.jpg). so how can i overwrite using only file name?, because user may upload any file type(jpg,png or gif), so how can i solve this?

I am not able to delete before upload new file because some time it will show upload error, but i have to delete before upload new file.

my sample code of file upload:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './profile-photos/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
$config['max_size'] = '400';
$config['max_width'] = '0';
$config['max_height'] = '0';                        
$config['file_name'] = $id; 
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

$this->load->library('upload',$config);                         
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('profilephoto'))
{
    echo $data['err_msg'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    echo "image not updated";
}
else
{
    echo "image update success";                    
}
```

Comment: When u uploaded file1 just use $_FILES[FILE2]

Comment: @devpro - i did not get. what is file2

Comment: means, replace the file, as other mate suggest

Answer (score 0):

Rename those.

```
if (file_exists($id . '.jpg') //use absolute path eg. FCPATH . 'profile-photos/' . $id . '.jpg'
{
    $file_extension = 'jpg';
    rename($id . '.jpg', $id . '_old.jpg')//absolute path too
}
elseif (file_exists($id . '.png') //use absolute path eg. FCPATH . 'profile-photos/' . $id . '.png'
{
    $file_extension = 'png';
    rename($id . '.png', $id . '_old.png')//absolute path too
}
elseif (file_exists($id . '.jpeg') //use absolute path eg. FCPATH . 'profile-photos/' . $id . '.jpeg' 
{
    $file_extension = 'jpeg';
    rename($id . '.jpeg', $id . '_old.jpeg')//absolute path
}
```

After this upload new file.
Than delete renamed files.

```
unset(FCPATH . "profile-photos/$id.$file_extension");
```

Comment: I think only `rename` is sufficient, no need to unset. it replaces complete file if file type is different also.

Comment: I used only `if else` everything working fine. it means `rename()` not creates `_old` file, it replaces complete file if different type also. so i did not get how this code works. and i written this code before `if(!$this->upload->do_upload('profilephoto'))`.

Comment: how `rename` deletes file? i am using codeigniter 3.0